# Adding Entity to List Becomes Null After Addition

Tags: java, list, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I'm creating a bunch of new `PrblFldrTbl` objects and adding them to a `@OneToMany` list in a `PrblFldr` object. This is done inside of a Jersey REST web service method and my `EntityManager` is injected like so:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="ProLabel")
private EntityManager em;
```

Then, inside of the REST method, I'm getting the `PrblFldr` object that we will be adding the `PrblFldrTbl` objects to from the `EntityManager` like so:

```
PrblFldr folder = em.find(PrblFldr.class, folderId);
```

Here's the part where I'm creating `PrblFldrTbl` objects:

```
List<PrblFldrTbl> tablesToAdd = new ArrayList<PrblFldrTbl>();
for (PrblFldrTbl table: folder.getPrblFldrTbls()) {
    // Only adds table if it is part of the previous revision
    if (table.getPrblFldrRvsn().getFldrRvsnId() == revisionSeq - 1) {
        // Duplicates the table but sets the revision to the provided one
        // Also associates the given PrblFldr object with the new PrblFldrTbl
        PrblFldrTbl newTable = makeNewRev(table, revision, folder);
        // Persists this new PrblFldrTbl object
        em.persist(newTable);

        // ... irrelevant stuff ...

        // Add the table to the list we're going to use later
        tablesToAdd.add(newTable);
    }
}
```

Here's the part where I'm taking all of those new `PrblFldrTbl` objects and adding them to the current `PrblFldr` object's `@OneToMany` list (doing it this way prevents errors related to concurrent modifications):

```
folder.getPrblFldrTbls().addAll(tablesToAdd);
```

When I check the `tablesToAdd` list, all of the `PrblFldrTbl` objects are correct. They're new, they were persisted to the database, etc. When I check the contents of `folder.getPrblFldrTbls()` after the `.addAll()` method, the `PrblFldrTbl` objects were all added correctly.

**But there's a catch!** When I access that same method (`folder.getPrblFldrTbls()`) in a different service call, those `PrblFldrTbl` objects that I added to the list have all become `null`. Everything is persisted in the database and all is correct, but something must be getting screwed up in the persistence context. I don't want to have to tell the `EntityManager` to go fetch everything again; when I persist it, it should stay! Any idea what's causing this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved my own problem... sort of. I knew that EclipseLink defaults all relationships to be lazily loaded, which is what I want. But, I assumed that when I called `folder.getPrblFldrTbls()`, it would load the associated `PrblFldrTbl` objects again. Something weird must be happening in the persistence context, but by placing a `FetchType.EAGER` on the `@OneToMany` annotation for the list of `PrblFldrTbl` objects in the `PrblFldr` entity, I solved this issue.

If anyone has any more information about why this occurs when the fetch type is lazy, please share. I would prefer to not use my solution above because it could cause performance issues (I don't always need to pull in the list of `PrblFldrTbl` objects).